# Загрузка фотографии vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, python-2.x

Собственно, вот мой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk_api, time, urllib, os, requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from re import escape



html_doc = urlopen('http://joyreactor.cc/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

login, password = 'выопавылпвыл', 'авоавловало'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()

contain = []

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    foo = img.get('src')
    if ('post' in foo) and (foo not in contain):
        contain.append(foo)
        urllib.urlretrieve(foo, filename="/root/foo.jpg") # сохранение картинки


        link = vk.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id = '152811311')
        DATA_UPLOAD_URL = link['upload_url']
        r = requests.post(DATA_UPLOAD_URL, files = {'photo': open('/root/foo.jpg', 'rb')})

        photo = r.json()['photo']
        photo = str(photo[1:-1])
        photo = str(json.loads(photo))
        photo = photo[1:-1] 



        params = {'hash': r.json()['hash'], 'server': r.json()['server'], 'photo': photo, 'group_id': '152811311'}
        print(params)
        print('Сервер:')
        print(r.json()['server'])
        print('Фото:')
        print(photo)
        print('Хэш:')
        print(r.json()['hash'])


        wallphoto = vk.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params)


        vk.wall.post(owner_id = '-152811311', from_group = '1', message = foo) # пост на стене
        print(contain)
        time.sleep(30)
```

А вот его вывод:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я уже несколько дней пытаюсь загрузить картинку. Дошел до этого этапа. Ошибка, как я понял, не дает никакой информации. Помогите...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66051/discussion-on-question-by-----vk-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация ВК какая-то кривая и постоянно путает новичков вроде вас, я им сейчас пожаловался в Поддержке.

В общем, строка `photo` в JSON-объекте, которая возвращается после загрузки файла с фотографией, не должна видоизменяться никаким образом; раскодировали JSON-ответ (у вас это `r.json()`), достали из ответа `server` `photo` `hash`, запихнули их как есть в `saveWallPhoto` — всё, больше ничего делать не надо.

```
answer = r.json()

wallphoto = vk.photos.saveWallPhoto(
    photo=answer['photo'],
    server=answer['server'],
    hash=answer['hash'],
    group_id='152811311',
)
```

В `wallphoto` у вас оказывается список из объектов с фотографиями. Получить идентификатор, который потом можно будет запихнуть как прикрепление к посту, можно следующим образом:

```
attachment_photo = 'photo{}_{}'.format(wallphoto[0]['owner_id'], wallphoto[0]['id'])
```

И потом запихнуть его в `attachments` при создании поста:

```
result = vk.wall.post(
    owner_id='-152811311',
    attachments=attachment_photo,
    # ... все остальные параметры
)
```