# Почему не прикрепляется изображение?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема, после выполнения кода ниже, отправляется только слово "привет", но фото не отправляется, почему? я же ее вроде прикрепил..

```
import vk
import requests
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id="***", user_login="***", 
user_password="***", scope="messages, status, wall, friends, photos") 
vk = vk.API(session) #АВТОРИЗОВЫВАЕМСЯ

getMes = vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id=211748612) #БЕРЕМ ЮРЛ
getUpload = getMes['upload_url']
file = {'file': open('newpng.png', 'rb')} #БЕРЕМ ФОТО
ur = requests.post(getUpload, files=file).json() #загружаем на сервер
result = vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(photo=ur['photo'], server=ur['server'], hash=ur['hash']) #СОХРАНЯЕМ
vk.messages.send(user_id=211748612, message='привет', attachments=result[0]['id'], v=5.38) #ПРИКРЕПЛЯЕМ САМО ФОТО И ОТПРАВЛЯЕМ
```

в чем может быть дело?
спасибо

Comment: Явно attachments неправильный. Однако почему-то документация ВК поленилась сообщить, как составить правильный, но можно попробовать [по аналогии с фотографией на стене](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715638/178213)

Comment: попробовал вот так: `attachments={result[0]['owner_id'],result[0]['id']}`, все равно не получилось

Comment: попробовал еще так: `attachment_photo = 'photo{}_{}'.format(result[0]['owner_id'], result[0]['id'])`    
 
`vk.messages.send(user_id=211748612, message='привет', attachments=attachment_photo, v=5.38)`,и тоже не получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import vkAPI, requests
ses = vkAPI.AuthSession('login', 'password')
api = vkAPI.API(ses)
url = api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()
req = requests.post(url['upload_url'], files={'file': open('image.img', 'rb')})
uploaded = api.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(**req.json())
api.messages.send(domain='user_domain', attachment="photo{}_{}".format(uploaded[0]['owner_id'], uploaded[0]['id']))
```

Всё вполне работает.

Вы указали **attachments**, а над указывать **attachment**

Comment: офигееееть........................ я в поддержку обратился, они даже не заметили опечатку, блин спасибо большое, неделю мучался с этой проблемой

Comment: просто для публикации нужно писать attachments, а я-то внимание на это не обратил..