# Где получить media_id для прикрепления фото к записи?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Загружаю фото на сервера ВКонтакте поочерёдным вызовом методов `photos.getWallUploadServer` и `photos.saveWallPhoto`, в результате чего получаю JSON-файл, где указаны `id`, `owner_id` и `album_id`, но нет `media_id`. Пытаюсь получить доступ к фотографии посредством открытия страницы `vk.com/photos<owner_id>_<id>`, где **owner_id** и **id** взяты из данных, полученных после запроса к методу `photos.saveWallPhoto`, но получаю сообщение **Ошибка доступа**. Если вместо id из запроса установить ID приложения, то получаю сообщение **Неизвестная ошибка**. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужно сперва опубликовать запись на стене с этой фотографией — ведь это же save**Wall**Photo

Comment: @andreymal так ведь мне нужно уже иметь загруженную фотографию, чтобы делать посты с ней.

Comment: `photo<owner_id>_<id>` у вас уже есть — с этим вполне можно сделать пост

Comment: Собсна я вот тут уже писал пример для питона https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715638

Comment: @andreymal так в том и дело, что я делаю пост, а он создаётся без картинки. `owner_id` у меня почему-то является не id группы, а id моей персональной страницы, а при попытке обратиться к странице `vk.com/photo<owner_id>_<id>` у меня возникает "Ошибка доступа". Посты в группе появляются, но без фотографий.

Comment: Там и должен быть id персональной страницы (я не знаю почему, но должен), не меняйте его и всё должно работать (у меня работает, например)

Comment: @andreymal вот параметр запроса `attachments` к `wall.post`: `&attachments=photo${imagePostData.response.owner_id}_${imagePostData.response.id}`. Но посты делаются без фотографий. Не знаю почему...

Comment: Потому что response — это массив, и вам ещё нужно не забыть достать первый элемент массива

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! Как всегда всё из-за моей чёртовой невнимательности...

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы загружали фото **ДЛЯ СТЕНЫ**, то чтобы фотография стала доступна ее надо выложить на стену(создать новую запись на стене с этой фотографией).